# Which is the best way to store a list of data in localStorage and display them when searched using a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, components, babeljs

I'm trying to build a movie directory kinda like a todo-list app but here you can store your favorite movies and can search and display them by searching with the name of the movie.
So I'm using the localStorage to store the data and then display when the search result matches the movie name string.
On 'submit' of a button I can see the localStorage has the data but the data is not stored permanently.
It just gets removed when I tried to enter the next input. So how can I resolve the issue and what are the best ways to store data efficiently.

```
<! Start of the snippet -->

        import React from 'react';
        import './App.css';
        import Search from './components/Search';
        import FormInput from './components/FormInput';
        import Show from './components/Show';
        import {Container, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';


        class App extends React.Component {

          userData;
          state = {
            
              movieName: '',
              ratings: '',
              duration: ''
            
          }

          

          handleMovieName = (e) =>{
            this.setState({movieName: e.target.value})
          }
          handleRatings = (e) => {
            this.setState({ratings: e.target.value})
          }
          handleDuration = (e) => {
            this.setState({duration: e.target.value})
          }
          handleSubmit = (e) => {
            console.log(`${this.state.movieName} ${this.state.ratings} ${this.state.duration}`);
            e.preventDefault();
          componentDidMount(){
            this.userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

            if(localStorage.getItem('user')){
              this.setState({
                movieName: this.userData.movieName,
                ratings: this.userData.ratings,
                duration: this.userData.duration
              })
            } else{
              this.setState({
                movieName: '',
                ratings: '',
                duration: ''
              })
            }
          }

          componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
            localStorage.setItem('movieName', JSON.stringify(nextState));
          }

        render() {
          return (
            <div>
              <header><h1>Netflix Movie Directory</h1></header>

                <main>
                <Search />
                <Container className="container1">
                  <Row noGutters="true">
                    <Col xs={12} md={8}>
                      <Show 
                        handleDuration = {this.state.duration}
                        handleRatings = {this.state.ratings}
                        handleMovieName = {this.state.movieName} />
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs={6} md={4}>
                      <FormInput 
                        handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} 
                        handleDuration = {this.handleDuration}
                        handleRatings = {this.handleRatings}
                        handleMovieName = {this.handleMovieName} />
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </Container>
          
                </main>
            </div>
          );
         }
        }

        export default App;


    <!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems very likely that the bug comes from a mismatch in localStorage keys.

You **never** set `user` key in localStorage but if it is not present, you reset component's state which triggers `componentWillUpdate` which will re-write info stored in local storage under `movieName` key.

So, probably you want to read `movieName` instead of `user` from local storage like this:

```js
componentDidMount(){
  const maybeMovieInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('movieName'));

  if(localStorage.getItem('movieName')){
    this.setState({
      movieName: maybeMovieInfo.movieName,
      ratings: maybeMovieInfo.ratings,
      duration: maybeMovieInfo.duration
    })
  } else{
    this.setState({
      movieName: '',
      ratings: '',
      duration: ''
    })
  }
}
```

Generally speaking, storing information of this type in local storage is a perfectly valid use case.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you need to use componentWillUpdate. It is marked as unsafe so try to avoid it. It is mentioned clearly in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating
So I suggest to remove this:

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
            localStorage.setItem('movieName', JSON.stringify(nextState));
          }
```

instead do the store update logic in your handleSubmit

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
            console.log(`${this.state.movieName} ${this.state.ratings} ${this.state.duration}`);
            localStorage.setItem('movieName', JSON.stringify(nextState));

        e.preventDefault();}
```

Comment: The handleSubmit will do the following things everytime submit is triggered, two things happen -
1. The form gets cleared for the next input
2. The data gets stored in the localStorage